# How does the ? operator interact with the From trait?

Tags: error-handling, rust, type-conversion, traits

Say I have the following:

```rust
use std::fs::File;

impl From<i32> for Blah {

    fn from(b:i32) -> Blah {
        Blah {}
    }
}

fn main() {}

enum MyError {
    ParseError,
}

impl From<std::io::Error> for MyError {
    fn from(_:std::io::Error) -> Self {
        MyError::ParseError
    }
}

fn get_result() -> Result<Blah, MyError> {
    let mut file = File::create("foo.txt")?;
}
```

This compiles fine. I don't understand how.

`File::create` throws an `std::io::error`, which we're trying to wrap in a `MyError`. But we never explicitly call `from` anywhere!? How does it compile?

As the comments from this answer [Rust understanding From trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57853235/rust-understanding-from-trait) indicate, you do have to explicitly call `from`.

So, how is the above snippet compiling?

Answer (score 4):

The magic is in the `?` operator.

```
let mut file = File::create("foo.txt")?;
```

expands to something like ([source](https://m4rw3r.github.io/rust-questionmark-operator))

```
let mut file = match File::create("foo.txt") {
    Ok(t)  => t,
    Err(e) => return Err(e.into()),
};
```

This uses the `Into` trait, which is the counterpart to the `From` trait: `e.into()` is equivalent to `T::from(e)`. Here you have the explicit conversion.

([There is an automatic `impl<T, U> Into<U> for T` for every `impl<T, U> From<T> for U`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html#implementors), which is why implementing `From` is enough.)

Answer (score 4):

The difference is stated in [The Rust Programming Language, chapter 9, section 2](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator), when talking about the `?` operator:

> Error values that have the `?` operator called on them go through the from function, defined in the `From` trait in the standard library, which is used to convert errors from one type into another. When the `?` operator calls the `from` function, the error type received is converted into the error type defined in the return type of the current function. This is useful when a function returns one error type to represent all the ways a function might fail, even if parts might fail for many different reasons. **As long as each error type implements the `from` function to define how to convert itself to the returned error type, the `?` operator takes care of the conversion automatically.**

You have provided this implementation of `From<std::io::Error>` for that error type, therefore the code will work and convert values of this type automatically.